# Number of subdirectories allowed

Tags: batch

I would like to know the number of sub-directories created authorized. Do you know what to do to find out?

Comment: I don't there is any rule like that by default; doing a infinity `mkdir sub cd sub` loop won't stop creating new subdirectories inside themself, until you kill his execution. Also, avoid to do it, it could corrupt the disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
let "limit = 0"
while(true)
do {
let "limit = limit + 1"
mkdir rep && cd rep && echo $limit
}
done
```

Comment: What is this good for? What will be achieved by it?